# Second alert not called following StorageArea.clear

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.storage.sync.clear(function() {
      alert("Nuked");
      chrome.storage.sync.set({"data_init": "0"}, function(result) {
        alert("nukedata: " + result.data_init);
      });
    });
```

In the above code, "Nuked" is displaying every time but the alert nested in the second callback function never displays. How can I ensure a "data_init" storage item is created and set following a storage clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set callback [does not echo items that were set](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-set). Your code does not get executed, as accessing `data_init` of `undefined` throws a runtime error.

You should check for `chrome.runtime.lastError` inside the callback; if it is undefined, items were saved.